# XL-Deploy Error: Error: this script should be run with the -expose-proxies flag. Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException:

Tags: java, command-line-interface, teamcity-9.0, deployit, xl-deploy

[root@piyushjoshi bin]# sh cli.sh
Username: admin
Password: 
Welcome to the XL Deploy Jython CLI!
Type 'help' to learn about the objects you can use to interact with XL Deploy.

XL Deploy Objects available on the CLI:

- deployit: The main gateway to interfacing with XL Deploy.
- deployment: Perform tasks related to setting up deployments
- factory: Helper that can construct Configuration Items (CI) and Artifacts
- repository: Gateway to doing CRUD operations on all types of CIs
- security: Access to the security settings of XL Deploy.
- task2: Access to the task block engine of XL Deploy.
- tasks: Access to the task engine of XL Deploy. !Deprecated! Use task2 instead.

To know more about a specific object, type .help()
To get to know more about a specific method of an object, type .help("")

Reading extension: ext/ci.py
Reading extension: ext/usageinfo.py

Error: this script should be run with the -expose-proxies flag.
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: SystemExit: 1 in  at line number 184
    at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.scriptException(PyScriptEngine.java:202)
    at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.eval(PyScriptEngine.java:42)
    at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.eval(PyScriptEngine.java:47)
    at com.xebialabs.deployit.cli.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.java:87)
    at com.xebialabs.deployit.cli.Cli.readExtensions(Cli.java:242)
    at com.xebialabs.deployit.cli.Cli.getNewInterpreter(Cli.java:135)
    at com.xebialabs.deployit.cli.Cli.main(Cli.java:101)
Caused by: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 184, in 
SystemExit: 1

```
at org.python.core.PySystemState.exit(PySystemState.java:1494)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(PyReflectedFunction.java:186)
at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(PyReflectedFunction.java:204)
at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:478)
at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:482)
at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:141)
at org.python.pycode._pyx1.f$0(<script>:270)
at org.python.pycode._pyx1.call_function(<script>)
at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:167)
at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1386)
at org.python.core.__builtin__.eval(__builtin__.java:497)
at org.python.core.__builtin__.eval(__builtin__.java:501)
at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.eval(PythonInterpreter.java:259)
at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.eval(PyScriptEngine.java:40)
... 5 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `usageinfo.py` script your having installed under `ext` probably is using some advanced features from the CLI. Can you run the same script using `-expose-proxies`?

So start up the CLI as follows:

```
sh cli.sh -expose-proxies
```